# Creating this numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following numpy array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,6,8])
```

I want to create another numpy array from `a` such that it contains all the different possible sums of TWO elements of `a`. It's easy to show then that there are `int(a.size*(a.size-1)/2)` different possible sums, composed from:

```
a[0] + a[1]
a[0] + a[2]
a[0] + a[3]
a[1] + a[2]
a[1] + a[3]
a[2] + a[3]
```

How can I construct a numpy array with the above sums as elements without using a double for loop (the only way I can think of it). For the above example, the output should be `[3,7,9,8,10,14]`

**MWE**

```
eff = int(a.size*(a.size-1)/2)
c = np.empty((0, eff))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `triu_indices`:

```
i0,i1 = np.triu_indices(4,1)
a[i0]
# array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6])
a[i1]
# array([2, 6, 8, 6, 8, 8])
a[i0]+a[i1]
# array([ 3,  7,  9,  8, 10, 14])
```

For more terms we need to build our own "nd_triu_idx". Here is how to do it for 3 terms out of a list of 5:

```
n = 5
full = np.mgrid[:n,:n,:n]
nd_triu_idx = full[:,(np.diff(full,axis=0)>0).all(axis=0)]
nd_triu_idx
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
#        [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3],
#        [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

To fully generalize the number of terms use something like

```
k = 4
full = np.mgrid[k*(slice(n),)]
```

etc.

Comment: This is the great! Can it easily be adapted to find all combinations of three element sums?

Comment: So for sum of three elements of the array shown in the OP, I expect to see something like [9,11,15,16]. How do I explicitly get this from your updated code? And how does it generalise to more terms (max number of terms is 4 for the question)

Comment: @Sid in that case you'd have to replace `n=5` with `n=4` and add as the last line `a[nd_triu_idx].sum(axis=0)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer, Thanks. Finally, if I wanted to do it for 4 terms out of a list of 5, would I just change the first two lines? `n = 5` `full = np.mgrid[:n,:n,:n,:n]`? If so is there a way to specify the result for the number of terms and the size of the list?

Comment: @Sid See update. Be warned that the `full` arrays will get rather large (k*n^k elements). Let me know if that's a problem.

Comment: Your code works great for the question presented. Say if `a` was a length 10 numpy array. How would I create an array composed of sums of 2 terms, 3 terms, 4 terms, ..., 10 terms.

Comment: @Sid If you don't care about the order of the sums, the easiest way of getting all of them would be `np.unpackbits(np.arange(1024,dtype='<u2')[:,None].view('u1'),axis=1,count=10,bitorder='little')@a`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200981/discussion-between-sid-and-paul-panzer).

Answer (score 2):

You can do combinations on your array of size 2 and sum each one:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

a = np.array([1,2,6,8])

print(list(map(sum, combinations(a, 2))))
# [3, 7, 9, 8, 10, 14]
```

Or using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,6,8,1])

b = a + a[:,None]
print(b[np.triu_indices(4, 1)])
# [ 3  7  9  8 10 14]
```

Comment: Since i'll be using the list, is it possible to write `b = list(map(sum, combinations(a, 2)))`?

Comment: Good case for `np.fromiter()` if you want a NumPy array back: `np.fromiter(map(sum, it.combinations(a, 2)), dtype=a.dtype)`

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` error.

Comment: @Sid, Make sure you don't name your list as `list`.

Comment: @Sid, You have previously defined some list with some built-ins I used in my code. It can be either `list` or `map`. Please check.

Comment: @Austin, the numpy method works. How can it be adapted if I wanted a list of all possible three element sums (as opposed to 2)?

Answer (score 0):

What about computing the cartesian product of exponentiated version of `a`?

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 8])[:, None]
>>> b = np.exp(a)
>>> np.unique(np.tril(np.log(np.dot(b, b.T)), k=-1))[1:]
array([ 3.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 14.])
```

Comment: This doesn't have the correct length. Should be a 1 by 6 array

Comment: This is not quite right (still has an extra zero in in), but fairly clever (and convoluted), so +1